# Open Ms Word in write mode using microsoft.office.interop.word

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to open a MS Word Document through C#. But the open method is opening the document in a read-only mode. I want the file to be opened in write mode without creating another copy of i, so that I can save the changes to Database.
Here is the code for opening the file.

```
public void def()
{
    Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document dd = app.Documents.Open("C:\\hi12.docx", ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing, ref Nothing,ref repair);
    dd.TrackRevisions = true;
    dd.CommandBars["Reviewing"].Controls["Reviewing Pane"].Execute();
    int count = dd.Words.Count;
    dd.Close(ref Nothing, ref format, ref Nothing);
}
```

Comment: You can see it..http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36432/Edit-Microsoft-Word-Document-From-Your-Application

Comment: Note that it's a horrible idea to ever use Office Interop from a server application (like ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.view.readinglayoutallowediting
Also you should not use interop when not running on a client (asp.net runs on a server).
You also definitely need to close your app.

Comment: Instead of interop what other Method I can use to open up the documents make changes and save it to database and track the changes made to it and the user who did it.? Please help